# Using other NPM packages in own cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I created an own cordova plugin for use in an Ionic 3 project.

The js-module requires other npm/node packages (in my case for XML processing).

e.g.
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

I read X articles about hooks and other crazy stuff, but nothing really helpful.

Is there no easy way to add such a trivial thing to the build-chain just by some simple configuration of the dependencies?

Edit:

Let´s take that simple plugin as example: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello

The *great* function in https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello/blob/master/www/hello.js should be able to use the *xmlbuilder*.

So I changed the file to:

```
/*global cordova, module*/
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

module.exports = {
    greet: function (name, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Hello", "greet", [name]);
    }
};
```

I added the module via `npm install` to the ionic project, but that doesn´t help. How can I make the modules somehow available for the plugins?

Comment: Please reduce your question to a piece of code and - or - error output. I'm sure you'll receive plenty of help if you provide specific information.

Comment: You can't and you should not. The javascript files in cordova plugins are just the interface to the native functionality, you should not do any work there (other than maybe a bit of mapping, asserting, ...), especially if this requires extra libraries. Imagine it as a bridge, you pass some action from your application to the bridge and the bridge passes it on to the native part of your application, a possible result is passed back using the same bridge. For what its worth: I have never seen a plugin which makes use of a library in its www folder.